# Image not visible

Tags: java, opengl, shader, lwjgl

I have been attempting to display a image using [38leinaD code](https://developer.oculusvr.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=88&start=10).

Here is a slightly modified version where I attempt to display the image:

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;

public class DistortionCorrection {

    public enum Eye {
        Left, Right
    };

    protected int shader=0;
    protected int vertShader=0;
    protected int fragShader=0;

    protected int colorTextureID;
    protected int framebufferID;
    protected int depthRenderBufferID;

    private int LensCenterLocation;
    private int ScreenCenterLocation;
    private int ScaleLocation;
    private int ScaleInLocation;
    private int HmdWarpParamLocation;

    // renderDistortedEye
    public static float K0 = 1.0f;
    public static float K1 = 0.22f;
    public static float K2 = 0.24f;
    public static float K3 = 0.0f;

    // Added
    BufferedImage panda;
    private static final int BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 4;
    int pandaID;

    private final static String VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE =
            "void main() {\n" +
                    "   gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;\n" +
                    "   gl_Position = gl_Vertex;\n" +
                    "}";

    private final static String FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE =
            "uniform sampler2D tex;\n" +
                    "uniform vec2 LensCenter;\n" +
                    "uniform vec2 ScreenCenter;\n" +
                    "uniform vec2 Scale;\n" +
                    "uniform vec2 ScaleIn;\n" +
                    "uniform vec4 HmdWarpParam;\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "vec2 HmdWarp(vec2 texIn)\n" +
                    "{\n" +
                    "   vec2 theta = (texIn - LensCenter) * ScaleIn;\n" +
                    "   float  rSq= theta.x * theta.x + theta.y * theta.y;\n" +
                    "   vec2 theta1 = theta * (HmdWarpParam.x + HmdWarpParam.y * rSq + " +
                    "           HmdWarpParam.z * rSq * rSq + HmdWarpParam.w * rSq * rSq * rSq);\n" +
                    "   return LensCenter + Scale * theta1;\n" +
                    "}\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "void main()\n" +
                    "{\n" +
                    "   vec2 tc = HmdWarp(gl_TexCoord[0].xy);\n" +
                    "   if (any(notEqual(clamp(tc, ScreenCenter-vec2(0.25,0.5), ScreenCenter+vec2(0.25, 0.5)) - tc, vec2(0.0, 0.0))))\n" +
                    "       gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n" +
                    "   else\n" +
                    "       gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, tc);\n" +
                    "}";

    public DistortionCorrection(int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        initShaders(VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE, FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE);
        initFBO(screenWidth, screenHeight);

        // Added
        glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0, -1, 1);
        try {
            panda = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/webstorms/Desktop/panda.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        pandaID = loadTexture(panda);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pandaID);
        // Added end

        Util.checkGLError();

        LensCenterLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "LensCenter");
        ScreenCenterLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "ScreenCenter");
        ScaleLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "Scale");
        ScaleInLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "ScaleIn");
        HmdWarpParamLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "HmdWarpParam");
        System.out.println(FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE);
        Util.checkGLError();
    }

    private void initFBO(int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        framebufferID = glGenFramebuffers();                                                                               
        colorTextureID = glGenTextures();                                                                                               
        depthRenderBufferID = glGenRenderbuffers();                                                                 

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebufferID);                                               

        // initialize color texture
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTextureID);                                                                 
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);                               
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0,GL_RGBA, GL_INT, (java.nio.ByteBuffer) null);
        //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
        //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTextureID, 0);

        // initialize depth renderbuffer
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBufferID);                               
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL14.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBufferID);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);                                                                   
    }

    public void beginOffScreenRenderPass() {

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);         
        Util.checkGLError();
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebufferID);
        Util.checkGLError();
    }

    public void endOffScreenRenderPass() {

    }

    public void renderToScreen() {
        Util.checkGLError();
        glUseProgram(shader);
        Util.checkGLError();


        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);   
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);                                   

        glClearColor (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTextureID);   

        renderDistortedEye(Eye.Left, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        renderDistortedEye(Eye.Right, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

        glUseProgram(0);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    }

    public void renderDistortedEye(Eye eye, float x, float y, float w, float h) {
        float as = w/h;

        float scaleFactor = 1.0f;
        Util.checkGLError();

        float DistortionXCenterOffset;
        if (eye == Eye.Left) {
            DistortionXCenterOffset = 0.25f;
        }
        else {
            DistortionXCenterOffset = -0.25f;
        }

        glUniform2f(LensCenterLocation, x + (w + DistortionXCenterOffset * 0.5f)*0.5f, y + h*0.5f);
        glUniform2f(ScreenCenterLocation, x + w*0.5f, y + h*0.5f);
        glUniform2f(ScaleLocation, (w/2.0f) * scaleFactor, (h/2.0f) * scaleFactor * as);;
        glUniform2f(ScaleInLocation, (2.0f/w), (2.0f/h) / as);

        glUniform4f(HmdWarpParamLocation, K0, K1, K2, K3);

        if (eye == Eye.Left) {
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f(0.0f, -1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex2f(-1.0f, 1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 1.0f);   glVertex2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
            glEnd();
        }
        else {
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
            glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f(0.0f, -1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f(1.0f, -1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 1.0f);   glVertex2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
            glEnd();           
        }
    }

    protected void initShaders(String vertexShader, String fragmentShader) {
        shader=glCreateProgram();

        vertShader=createVertShader(vertexShader);
        fragShader=createFragShader(fragmentShader);

        glAttachShader(shader, vertShader);
        glAttachShader(shader, fragShader);

        glLinkProgram(shader);
        glValidateProgram(shader);
    }

    private int createVertShader(String vertexCode){
        vertShader=glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

        if (vertShader==0) {
            return 0;
        }

        glShaderSource(vertShader, vertexCode);
        glCompileShader(vertShader);

        return vertShader;
    }

    private int createFragShader(String fragCode){

        fragShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        if (fragShader==0) {
            return 0;
        }
        glShaderSource(fragShader, fragCode);
        glCompileShader(fragShader);

        return fragShader;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            DisplayMode displayMode = Display.getDesktopDisplayMode();
            Display.setDisplayMode(displayMode);
            Display.setTitle("Barrel Distorion Shader");
            Display.setFullscreen(true);
            PixelFormat pixelFormat = new PixelFormat(8, 8, 8);
            Display.create(pixelFormat);
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DistortionCorrection shader = new DistortionCorrection(640, 400);

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            shader.beginOffScreenRenderPass();

            glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
        //  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadIdentity();

            // Content

            // Added
            //   glPushMatrix();
            //    glTranslatef(100, 100, 0);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            {
                glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
                glVertex2f(0, 0);

                glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
                glVertex2f(Display.getWidth(), 0);

                glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
                glVertex2f(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());

                glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
                glVertex2f(0, Display.getHeight());
            }
            glEnd();
           //  glPopMatrix();
             // Added end

            /*
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
                glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f + 0.1f * i);
                glVertex2f(1.0f, -1.0f + 0.1f * i);
            }
            for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
                glVertex2f(-1.0f + 0.1f * i, -1.0f);
                glVertex2f(-1.0f + 0.1f * i, 1.0f);
            }
            glEnd(); */

            shader.endOffScreenRenderPass();
            shader.renderToScreen();

            Display.sync(60);
            Display.update();
        }
    }
     public static int loadTexture(BufferedImage image){

          int[] pixels = new int[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()];
            image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels, 0, image.getWidth());

            ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(image.getWidth() * image.getHeight() * BYTES_PER_PIXEL); //4 for RGBA, 3 for RGB

            for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++){
                for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++){
                    int pixel = pixels[y * image.getWidth() + x];
                    buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF));     // Red component
                    buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF));      // Green component
                    buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF));               // Blue component
                    buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF));    // Alpha component. Only for RGBA
                }
            }

            buffer.flip(); //FOR THE LOVE OF GOD DO NOT FORGET THIS

            // You now have a ByteBuffer filled with the color data of each pixel.
            // Now just create a texture ID and bind it. Then you can load it using 
            // whatever OpenGL method you want, for example:

          int textureID = glGenTextures(); //Generate texture ID
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID); //Bind texture ID

            //Setup wrap mode
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

            //Setup texture scaling filtering
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

            //Send texel data to OpenGL
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

            //Return the texture ID so we can bind it later again
          return textureID;
       }

}
```

Comment: This does not surprise me at all, you are not transforming your vertices (you have an identity matrix for projection and modelview) so `glVertex2f(Display.getWidth(), 0);` is well outside of normalized device coordinate range: [-1,1]. At the very least, you will probably need to define a projection matrix.

Comment: Thank you. I'm very new to openGL. How would I define a projection matrix?

Comment: You should have a call like `glOrtho (0.0f, Display.getWidth (), Display.getHeight (), 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);` after you set the MatrixMode to `GL_PROJECTION`. You can completely skip this if all you want is quad that covers the entire screen though - Use the vertex points (-1,-1) for your bottom-left corner and (1,1) for the top-right when you use an identity modelview and projection matrix.

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying what you have mentioned, but can't seem to get it to work. Could you perhaps update the code, and comment what you've changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As-per your comments, I made a couple of changes to your code that might achieve what you want:

```
//
// This polygon is wound Clockwise instead of Counter-Clockwise; when you start
//   using projection matrices and face culling this is a concept you will need
//     to understand. 
//
// Counter-Clockwise is the preferred winding order in OpenGL, by the way - I
//   just wanted to show this to you for future reference.
//
glBegin (GL_QUADS);
{
  glTexCoord2f ( 0.0f,  0.0f);
  glVertex2f   (-1.0f, -1.0f); // Bottom-left

  glTexCoord2f ( 0.0f,  1.0f);
  glVertex2f   (-1.0f,  1.0f); // Top-Left

  glTexCoord2f ( 1.0f,  1.0f);
  glVertex2f   ( 1.0f,  1.0f); // Top-Right

  glTexCoord2f ( 1.0f,  0.0f);
  glVertex2f   ( 1.0f, -1.0f); // Bottom-Right
}
glEnd ();
```

This code uses normalized device coordinates so that you do not have to know the dimensions of your window in order to create a quad that fills the entire screen <sub>(and more importantly does not need a non-identity projection matrix).</sub>

I do not know if this will fix your entire problem, but it is definitely a start.